# logrotate renaming original file to mylog.log.1 but then not using mylog.log

Tags: ubuntu, logrotate

I'm having an issue with logrotate on Ubuntu 14.04. not rotating my log file correctly. It is currently renaming mylog.log to mylog.log.1, but it then continues to use the file mylog.log.1 to log messages, instead of using mylog.log.

Under what conditions can this occur?

Answer (score 2):

restart or HUP the daemon which writes to this logfile. 
See `postrotate` and `prerotate` in logrotate manpage.

Answer (score 1):

You should restart/HUP the program using the `postrotate` directive, as per Ipor's answer.

A short explanation of the technical reason: your program is locking to the inode of `mylog.log`, and when logrotate moves the logfile, your program is still writing to that same inode. inodes don't contain nor care about file names. So by restarting your program, it is not using that old inode anymore and will begin logging to the new file.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot restart the application (which is run as a daemon) - it must stay running 24/7. The application opens the log files, writes to it, does an fflush and closes the file.

Is there anyway to indicate to logrotate, to perform it's operation, when I know the log file is closed?

How do other applications, such as apache and others that must run 24/7, handle the inode/log issue?